# The Internal format of OpenGL CUDA interop

Tags: opengl, cuda

I use CUDA surface Reference to write and read OpenGL 3D Texture fllowing this post [Write to 3D OpenGL textures in CUDA ...](http://rauwendaal.net/2011/12/02/writing-to-3d-opengl-textures-in-cuda-4-1-with-3d-surface-writes/) .

There is a problem confused me.
For example,this function

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_INTENSITY, volDim_.x, volDim_.y
        , volDim_.z, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, getVolumeTypeGL(vol), vol->getData());
```

the third parameter is internal format.

In CUDA kernel,I need write or read the texture,like below code,

```
ElementType v;
surf3Dread(&v,surfaceRef,x*sizeof(ElementType),y,z);
surf3Dwrite(&v,surfaceRef,x*sizeof(ElementType),y,z);
```

I don't know how to match Internal Format with ElementType.
Example

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_INTENSITY, volDim_.x, volDim_.y
    , volDim_.z, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vol->getData());
```

In host memory,the type of volume data type is unsigned char.
Which ElementType shuld I choose?

```
uchar4 or uchar ,or float
```

My some code could find in here [My GitHub](https://github.com/feizcnu/CUDA-OpenGL-Interop-3D-Texture)

**UPDATE:**

I have solved this problem.

GL_RGBA32F ----  float4

GL_RGBA    ----  uchar4

GL_INTENSITY --  uchar

Comment: Please add your solution as an *answer* to your question, rather than an EDIT. It is perfectly OK to answer your own question, and you will also be able to eventually accept the answer. This is how questions are marked as solved on [SO], rather than by editing the question title. Please don't do it that way. Thanks

Comment: @talonmies Thanks,I will do that soon!

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the internal format of `glTeximage3D` is `GL_INTENSITY`, the element type of `surf3Dread` or `surf3Dwrite` is unsigned char. `GL_RGBA32F` matches `float4` and `GL_RGBA` matches `uchar4`.